# Enviar dos identificadores de mi datatable Javascript PHP

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatables

Espero puedan ayudarme a solucionar mi problema, el detalle es que quiero enviar dos identifier de mi datatable al momento de que doy Enter, claro que funciona solo con un solo identifier, pero al incorporar un segundo header no funciona. Anteriormente vi algunos ejemplos en otras preguntas pero veo que no funciona conmigo, algo estaré haciendo mal.

Actualmente tengo mi código así:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dataTable').Tabledit({
                deleteButton: false,
                editButton: false,
                columns: {
                    identifier: [0, 'art_id'],

                    editable: [
                        [1, 'skuHijo'],
                        [2, 'skuPadre'],
                        [3, 'marca'],
                        [5, 'modelo'],
                        [6, 'linkImagen'],
                        [7, 'linkImagen2'],
                        [8, 'linkImagen3']
                    ]
                },
                hideIdentifier: true,
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/Productos/editarTablaYuju'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Mi vista es así

```
<div id="layoutSidenav_content">
    <main>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h4 class="mt-4"><?php echo $titulo; ?></h4>
            <?php
            // Display Response
            if (session()->has('message')) {
            ?>
                <div class="alert <?= session()->getFlashdata('alert-class') ?>">
                    <?= session()->getFlashdata('message') ?>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>

            <?php $validation = \Config\Services::validation(); ?>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/productos/exportMkLINKS"><span class="fa fa-download"></span>Export CVS</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#import">
                Import CVS
            </button>

            <div>
                <label>Coloca el mouse sobre el encabezado sin hacer click para ver informacion sobre el campo si tienes alguna duda</label>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>skuHijo</th>
                            <th>skuPadre</th>
                            <th>marca</th>
                            <th>color_id</th>
                            <th>modelo</th>
                            <th>linkImagen</th>
                            <th>linkImagen2</th>
                            <th>linkImagen3</th>
                            <th>color_id</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>skuHijo</th>
                            <th>skuPadre</th>
                            <th>marca</th>
                            <th>color_id</th>
                            <th>modelo</th>
                            <th>linkImagen</th>
                            <th>linkImagen2</th>
                            <th>linkImagen3</th>
                            <th>color_id</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($datos as $dato) { ?>
                            <tr id="<?php echo $dato['art_id'] ?>">
                                <td><?php echo $dato['art_id']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dato['skuHijo']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dato['skuPadre']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dato['marca']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dato['nombreColor']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dato['modelo']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dato['linkImagen']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dato['linkImagen2']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dato['linkImagen3']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $dato['color_id']; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                <a href=""></a>
                                </td>



                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dataTable').Tabledit({
                deleteButton: false,
                editButton: false,
                columns: {
                    identifier: [0, 'art_id'],

                    editable: [
                        [1, 'skuHijo'],
                        [2, 'skuPadre'],
                        [3, 'marca'],
                        [5, 'modelo'],
                        [6, 'linkImagen'],
                        [7, 'linkImagen2'],
                        [8, 'linkImagen3']
                    ]
                },
                hideIdentifier: true,
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/Productos/editarTablaYuju'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-confirma" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Eliminar Registro</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Deseas eliminar este registro?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Si</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="import" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">IMPORTAR</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post" action="<?= site_url('productos/importFileLINKS') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!--Actualiza Inicial Claro-->
                            <label>Importar Links (ean, linkImagen, linkImagen2, linkImagen3)</label>
                            <br>
                            <label for="file">Importar Archivo:</label>
                            <br>
                            <input type="file" class="btn btn-info" id="file" name="file" />


                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Import CSV">
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y mis CDNs en mi header:

```
   <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/jquery-tabledit-1.2.3/jquery.tabledit.min.js"></script>
```

Claramente estoy haciendo algo mal, les agradecería bastante su ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Podrías añadir los CDNs de las librerías que estas usando?

Comment: Parece que quieres encabezado y pie de tabla y el contenido de `<tfoot>... </tfoot>` debe estar debajo de `</tbody>`.

Comment: Listo @S.Wasta agregados

Comment: puedes agregarlo así `identifier:[[0, 'art_id'], [2, "otro"]]`

Comment: No funciono el puedes agregarlo así identifier:[[0, 'art_id'], [2, "otro"]]